# Defining Firebase Function Return Types in Firebase using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to define what a Firebase function's return type using TypeScript?

For example:

```
export const helloWorld = https.onCall(async (): Promise<string> => {}
```

The return of the function within the onCall() parameter is specified as `Promise<string>`, but is there a way to show that `helloWorld` is meant to return a string promise? I am only able to assign the function its default type given by TypeScript and not `Promise<string>`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the definition of onCall.  All you can do is return a promise that becomes fulfilled with the payload of the response to send.  It's up to you to return a valid object that can be serialized as JSON.

If you want create another plain function with a return type of `Promise<string>`, then feel free to do that, then call that function from within onCall.

Answer (score 0):

Has the same issue - best I could do was type casting the function in the client.